# Why are there two ways to write inline assembly with gcc?

Tags: gcc

```
asm volatile(...);

__asm__ __volatile__(...);
```

I see both are used; why create some duplicate stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard reserves 'asm' for use by users for any purpose.  Therefore, GCC provides the `__asm__` notation to avoid running into the user's name space (because identifiers starting with double underscore are reserved for the implementation).

The notation with the double underscore is ungainly, so GCC provides the pleasanter interface without the double underscores.  But if you turn on a standard-compliant compilation mode (such as `-std=c99`), the `asm` option is turned off.  By writing with the double underscore notation, it is always available.

So, `asm` is pleasanter to read, but `__asm__` is compliant with the C standard.

Comment: Does the standard reserve `volatile`?

Comment: The keyword `volatile` is part of the standard, unconditionally. By contrast, `asm` is not a keyword in the standard, and is not in the namespace reserved for the implementation.  I don't know why the `__volatile__` is 'needed' or 'used'; I'd not seen it used with assembler before.  The GCC Inline Assembly HOWTO referenced by ipapadop shows how `volatile` is used with `asm`.

Answer (score 0):

From [GCC Inline Assembly HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s4) "You might have noticed that here I’ve used `asm` and `__asm__`. Both are valid. We can use `__asm__` if the keyword `asm` conflicts with something in our program."